# Erro tempo de execução 91, Var do Obj ou Var do bloco With não foi definida

Tags: excel-vba

Estou criando um gatilho de envio de e-mail baseado na condição de mudança em qualquer célula de uma coluna. Consegui criar o macro em uma planilha, mas em outra utilizei a mesma lógica e trocando somente as coordenadas e nessa segunda planilha está acusando erro.

Pretendo usar o valor de algumas células para complementar o texto do corpo do e-mail, mas está dando erro 91 sendo que este mesmo código está rodando em outro lugar.

Aqui está o trecho onde o problema está acusando na variável BodyMid

```
Dim xRg As Range

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error Resume Next
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    Set xRg = Intersect(Range("F3:F100"), Target) 
    'Range baseado na coluna F, que contém os dias restantes das certidões

    If IsNumeric(Target.Value) And Target.Value = 15 Then
        Call Mail_small_Text_Outlook
    End If
End Sub

Sub Mail_small_Text_Outlook()
    Dim xOutApp As Object
    Dim xOutMail As Object
    Dim BodyHead, BodyMid, BodyBot As String
    Set xOutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set xOutMail = xOutApp.CreateItem(0)    

    With xOutMail
        'Texto do corpo do e-mail em HTML
        BodyHead = "<h4>Lembrete!</h4><br><br> " & vbNewLine & vbNewLine
        BodyMid = "</br></br> O seguinte documento de " & xRg.Offset(, -2) & " está prestes a expirar:" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine _
        & "<table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=10 border=1><tr><th> Documento </th><th> Data de Emissão</th><th>Dias a vencer</th>" _
        & "<th> Links Para Emissão</th></tr><tr><td>" & xRg.Offset(, -5) & "</td><td>" & xRg.Offset(, -3) _
        & "</td><td>" & xRg & "</td><td>" & xRg.Offset(, 2) & "</td></tr></table>" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine
```

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Comment: Meu caro, se puder, indique a linha em que ocorreu o erro e coloque o resto do código, o qual está interrompido.